# CSS3 "drop-shadow" on png with inset

Tags: css, dropshadow

Ok I can add shadows to transparent pngs with this:

```
.drop-shadow 
{
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow (0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow (0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow (0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-o-filter: drop-shadow (0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
filter: drop-shadow (0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}
```

(At least on some browsers)

How would I then change the code to display inset shadows ?

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
#yellow{ 
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #FFFF00; 
-moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px  #FFFF00; 
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #FFFF00; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Im not talking about the box-shadow property...Its the "drop-shadow"